# How to check if the function of an element is contained in a collection?

Tags: java, collections, contains

I'd like to override the .cointains method of a collection. I need for it to return positive not only if it finds the exact match, but also if it finds a slightly different element than the ones contained in the list. The criteria are inside a method that I can call .almostSimilarTo().

How to implement this properly? Are lambdas required?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by slightly different element? What if the collection has objects? I think your question is kind of vague.

Answer (score 2):

In the Java Collection classes, `contains()` uses the `equals()` method of the objects in the collection to determine if the element is in the collection. Override the `.equals()` method on the objects you are inserting into your collection, and have the `.equals()` method use the logic in your `.almostSimilarTo()` method.

When overriding `equals()`, make sure you understand [the `equals() hashCode() contract`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

Answer (score 1):

This is insane practice to override collection methods.

Try to implement this logic somewhere else. For example, your class can implement Comparable, or you can use Comparator, or sooo many other options.

Comment: Which other options?